# What is windows CE OS ? How to install it from scrach on blank HDD?

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I want to install windows CE on one of my HDD . I tried a lot to find image of this OS, but did not get even single bootable image file over internet.
Does any one know the image link or How to install Windows CE(latest) from scrach?

Below are the few  searched links :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms905319.aspx\
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2009/06/10/steps-needed-to-install-windows-embedded-ce-6-0-from-scratch.aspx

Even after going through these links also, unable to find the answer of my query.

Please help?

Comment: Windows CE runs on specific devices, with a limited set of processors supported, and furthermore needs to be customised for the specific device. So I do not think you can expect to get an off-the-shelf CE OS and "install" it on a blank HDD. It will not boot on a standard PC. I believe the Mike Hall blog link you cited is about installing the Windows CE 6.0 __development tools__, not an __OS__.

Answer (score 0):

Windows CE OS for your device is highly dependent on the processor and the peripherals that your device has.

So, if you are not a platform (OS) developer, you should contact your OEM for the OS images.

If you are OS developer (I mean, you are OEM), then only you can refer above links. They are meant for WinCE platform developers.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/bspcatalog.aspx) is a list of BSP (They may also provide you binaries for evaluation) and OEM.